# Limit to the first 10 elements of a model in the controller

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I'm struggling to understand how promises work in the controller. I'd like to display just the first 10 `sortedShips` in my template but I can't find a way to get `slice(0,10)` working in my controller.

*How can I limit `sortedShips` or a new property to the first 10 elements only?*

**app/controllers/index.js**

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Controller.extend({
  shipSort: ['name:asc'],
  sortedShips: Ember.computed.sort('model.ships', 'shipSort').property('model.ships')
});
```

Comment: I guess you meant `slice`, not `split`?

Comment: Yes, your right. I ment `slice`. Fixed it.

Answer (score 3):

Not sure what `split()` is, but Ember's [computed.filter](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.computed.html#method_filter) function should do the trick:

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Controller.extend({
    shipSort: ['name:asc'],
    // You don't need the .property() here, Ember does that for you
    sortedShips: Ember.computed.sort('model.ships', 'shipSort'),
    firstTenShips: Ember.computed.filter('sortedShips', function(ship, index) {
        return (index < 10);
    })
});
```